# Customize the QRScanner camera view in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I am using the QRScanner cn1lib and it is working alright. I wanted to customize and draw a square on the camera which will scan the QR code. I have no idea how to go about it.

```
    public void scanQRCode() {
    final android.app.Activity ctx = com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity();
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, ZBarScannerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_MODES, new int[]{Symbol.QRCODE});

    com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.startActivityForResult(intent, new IntentResultListener() {
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                QRScanner.getCallback().scanCompleted(data.getStringExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_RESULT), "QRCODE", data.getStringExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_RESULT).getBytes());
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                if (data != null) {
                    String error = data.getStringExtra(ZBarConstants.ERROR_INFO);
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(error)) {
                        QRScanner.getCallback().scanError(100, error);
                    } else {
                        QRScanner.getCallback().scanCanceled();
                    }
                } else {
                    QRScanner.getCallback().scanCanceled();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is my native implementation which I got from source. Please guide me in creating the square on the camera screen. I have very little knowledge about android, so please be explicit with details. Any sources for reference will be much appreciated.

Comment: You will have to build a custom camera application in order to do this. You will then be able to draw over the top of your camera video feed.

Comment: You can draw the square on the camera in native code, not from the Codename One code. You'll need to modify the cn1lib's sources for that.

Comment: I do know that I must modify the cn1lib's sources, but I do not know how to  go about it. I have read about modifying the Preview for the camera, but most of them use xml for layouts. Where should I put my xml so that it is picked up by android?

Comment: The XML layout can always be handcoded in Android, I'm not an Android guy so in a way this is more of an Android question. Every XML element in the Android layout XML has a Java class to match.